# Joining tables and creating a json out of the joined information

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, join, deno

Is there a way to join 2 tables with one query to DB in a way when records from one table are put as an array value in a 'new' column in another table?

*(It's clear how to do it with 2 queries to both tables and processing results in code, but is there a way to use only one SELECT with joining the tables "during" the query?)*

So, here is a simple example:

Table 1:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 |
| 2 | v2 |

Table 2:

| id | id_t1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | v3 |
| 2 | 1 | v4 |
| 3 | 2 | v5 |

As a query result of selecting all the values from Table 1 joined with Table 2 there should be the next array of objects *(to make the example more general id_t1 from Table 2 is filtered from the joined results)*:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: v1,
    newColumnForJoinedValuesFromTable2: [ { id: 1, value: v3 }, { id: 2, value: v4} ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: v2,
    newColumnForJoinedValuesFromTable2: [ { id: 3, value: v5 } ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your json by stacking twice the following functions:

- `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`, to build your jsons, given <key,value> pairs
- `JSON_AGG`, to aggregate your arrays

```
WITH tab2_agg AS (
    SELECT id_t1, 
           JSON_AGG(
               JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id'   , id_, 
                                 'value', value_)
           ) AS tab2_json
    FROM tab2
    GROUP BY id_t1
)
SELECT JSON_AGG(
           JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id'                                ,       id_,
                             'value'                             ,    value_,
                             'newColumnForJoinedValuesFromTable2', tab2_json)
       ) AS your_json
FROM       tab1
INNER JOIN tab2_agg
        ON tab1.id_ = tab2_agg.id_t1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xNvhKtMUeHs4zQRBTUZE5/0).

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_agg(json_build_object(...))` and `group by`.

```sql
select json_agg(to_json(t)) as json_result from
(                
 select t1.id, t1.value,
   json_agg(json_build_object('id',t2.id,'value',t2.value)) as "JoinedValues" 
 from t1 join t2 on t2.id_t1 = t1.id
 group by t1.id, t1.value
) as t;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9L3CSmZP59G6FMuLm7TUht/1)